# weird output of python translate module

Tags: python

I'm trying to wrap my brain around Python `translate` module, here's my code:

```
from translate import translator
# give back a weird three-d list 
translator = translator("en","zh","this is an example")
print(translator[0][0][0])
```

I don't quite get why it gives back a weird three-D list, and I can't seem to find any documentation on this. Is there a more elegant way to get the direct translated words back except for using a [0][0][0]?

Comment: Can you show how your output looks like? I don't if _everybody_ who wants to help you will want to install `translate` ;)

Comment: Is it a good idea to call your variable `translator`? If I'm looking at the correct package, its example uses `translation`. (And non-offensive sample text.)

Answer (score 1):

The example gives

```
from translate import Translator
translator= Translator(to_lang="zh")
translation = translator.translate("This is a pen.")
```

that means that if you format your code like

```
from translate import translator
# give back a regular unic0de string :)
translator = translator(to_lang="zh")
translation = translator.translate("this is an example")
```

then you can print `translation`  and it will give you  a single unicode string. Comment is optional.